# Improve val replace with jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace

Is it a way to improve this infamous syntax... (with arrays)?

```
$("#rte").val(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(':)','<img src="rte/icons/emoticon_happy.png" />')
});
$("#rte").val(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(';)','<img src="rte/icons/emoticon_wink.png" />')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this code way more extensible by supplying a dictionary for all of your smiles and looping through them:

```
var smileDict = {
  happy: ':)',
  wink:  ';)',
  sad:   ':(',
  cool:  'B)'
}

$('#rte').val(function(i, v) {
    for (var p in smileDict) {
        if (smileDict.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            v = v.replace(smileDict[p], '<img src="rte/icons/emoticon_' + p + '.png" />');
        }
    }
    return v;
});
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/mpx8r/1/)

---

EDIT: To have this update a preview area like requested in the comments:

```
var smileDict = {
  happy: ':)',
  wink:  ';)',
  sad:   ':(',
  cool:  'B)'
};

var rteVal = $('#rte').val();

for (var p in smileDict) {
    if (smileDict.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        rteVal = rteVal.replace(smileDict[p], '<img src="rte/icons/emoticon_' + p + '.png" />');
    }
}

$('#previewcontent').html(rteVal);
```

Comment: +1, mVchr. Wow! The solution is more elegant than I had imagined. Thanks. "Vote Up Requires 15 reputation (click this box is to dismiss)," how to?... Sorry. Regards.

Comment: Not if he ends up incorporating 20 smileys, then it's actually less code that's easier to maintain.

Comment: @Jakub Hampl - But you should concentrate on how happy the code is :)

Comment: Thank you again. Supplementary question, without wanting to emphasize ... If I want to create a preview area (like "preview" id), how to just replace the image in the preview and not in Textarea? Vincent

Comment: Store `$('#rte').val()` to a variable.  Change the `for (var p in smileDict)` etc to affect that variable instead of `v`.  Then insert that variable into `preview.html(variable)`

Comment: @mVcher Like this? `$('#previewcontent').html(rte); var rte = $("#rte").val(); var smileDict = { happy: ':)', wink: ';)', sad: ':(', cool: 'B)' } rte { for (var p in smileDict) { return replace(smileDict[p], '<img src="rte/icons/emoticon_' + p + '.png" />'); } });` Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#rte").val(function(i, v) {
  return v
  .replace(':)','<img src="rte/icons/emoticon_happy.png" />')
  // ...
  .replace(';)','<img src="rte/icons/emoticon_wink.png" />');
});
```